# VueJS - Get child width using $refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to extract the `clientWidth` of a child component inside VueJS. I'm calling `$refs` inside `mounted`, and assign its value to some data:

```js
this.width = this.$refs.refName.clientWidth
```

The issue is that the width of this component is defined as 100% the one of its parent. But according to Vue lifecycle, the child DOM will be mounted before its parent. That causes the width in the child to always be 0 at mounted, because its parent isn't rendered yet.
My only solution would be to hardcode values in CSS, but I'd like to avoid that. What is the best way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try using $nextTick():

```
this.$nextTick(
    () => { this.width = this.$refs.refName.clientWidth); }
);
```

This will run after finishing all of the pending Vue work and browser updates. So, it should catch the element at that point.

If that still doesn't work (for various reasons it can be delayed beyond that point at times), you are usually stuck with a window.setTimeout() call with a kludgy delay value in it.

What is a little better in that case but more work is a window.setInterval() hander that loops waiting for the element to finally be drawn and gain a width.

One thing you cannot do is bind to that value and expect it to work. `$refs` is *not* reactive nor are any of a DOM's element attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I hope one of them will solve my issue.

Comment: Should not work with an arrow function, because this will be null.